# Linux Deploy Ubuntu share folder

Tags: linux, kernel, file-sharing

I wasn't sure if I had to ask this question on a Linux Exchange or on the Android one, but since folder sharing is working fine on the Linux that are running on my computer, I thought that it is an Android side issue.
I am trying to share a folder between two Linux Deploy environments. I have tried to install `nfs-kernel-server` however I am having an error showing that the kernel does not support nfs. When I am using `uname -a` the kernel that Ubuntu prints is the Android's one so I guess that the Android kernel does not support the nfs module.
I have, also, tried using Samba. The server side was set up successfully. When I am trying to mount the shared folder using `mount -t cifs //192.168.1.5/mirror /mirror`, I am facing a mount error `cifs filesystem not supported by the system`. After some googling I found out that using `modprobe cifs` could resolve the issue however the module cifs does not exist on the Android kernel. It seems that the issue in both cases the issue seems to be the Android kernel, is there any way to add `nfs` or `cifs` support to the Android kernel? If that's not possible how could I share a folder between two Linux Deploy environments?

Comment: isn't ssh an option to you?

Comment: For NFS client support build your kernel with confirmation options `CONFIG_NFS_V[2|3|4|4_1|4_2]`. For server support build with `CONFIG_NFSD[_V[3|4]]`. For CIFS build with `CONFIG_CIFS[_SMB2]`. If rebuilding kernel is not an option for you, use SAMBA simply like FTP, without mounting CIFS. Or go with `rclone` or SSHFS. Both rely on FUSE. `rsync` also works over SSH with better performance. SFTP and FTP are also considerable options. Occasionally I use all of them on Android devices.

Comment: @alecxs The issue with ssh is that it would be hard to set it up for more devices if that is required later on and that it is hard to make it realtime

Comment: @IrfanLatif is there any tutorial I could follow on how to build my android kernel with NFS support?